# Hide weekend in SP2010 Calendar?

Tags: 2010, jquery

I'm trying to hide the weekends in my SP2010 calendar and all the sites online links to

http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/12/17/calendar-weekdays-only/

I tried getting this to work and it seems like this only works for MOSS2007. I tried putting in the jQuery file in my site directory but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The most likely issue with using that code is that your SP site doesn't contain the same elements. For example, the code is looking for an element with `id="CalViewTable1"`. When I inspected the calendar in my test site, there is no `CalViewTable1`. Instead I found that I do have a `table` with `class="ms-acal-month"`. This would then be the basis for manipulation.

As a note, that code is not using jQuery; only simple JavaScript. You should learn both of these to build your own solution and follow the same logic, or modify the script you found.